# jqGrid - Is it possible to put the navButtons in the grid's Caption/title bar?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have several buttons on the bottom of the my grid, and on a mobile device, they interfere with the paging buttons.

Since the grid's Caption/title bar is pretty empty, I was wondering if there was a configuration option that would allow the buttons to be placed on the right hand side of the grid caption/title bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want, then you should just use `toppager: true` instead of (or together with) `pager: true`. By the way, you can remove `caption` parameter of jqGrid to have the grid *without* any caption. As the result you will have the grid with navigator buttons over the grid.

**UPDATED:** You can use `pagerpos` and `recordpos` options to *merge* the blocks with the navigator buttons, pager info and the `<span>` with information added by `viewrecords: true`. You can use additional CSS rules to display the information better. For example you can try CSS rules like

```css
.ui-pager-control>.ui-pg-table>tbody>tr>td>table.ui-pg-table {
    display: inline-block;
    top: .6em;
}
.ui-pager-control>.ui-pg-table>tbody>tr>td>.ui-paging-info {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Not quite. I did try with toppager:true however this just duplicates the buttons and the paging to a new bar above the table headers. In my case, since I have several buttons, when you load on a smaller screen such as an iPad in portrait mode, the buttons overlap the page left and page right buttons. What I would like to do is move the buttons to the Caption/Title bar instead of in the same bar as the pager.

Comment: @MarkT: I still don't see any differences ans the usage of `toppager` is the standard way. All other problems with the look of the top pager can be easy solved. For example you can use `pagerLeftWidth` and `pagerRightWidth` options to reserve specified place for the part of the pager. Try to add something like `pagerLeftWidth: 680` to your grid. You can remove `viewrecords: true` to save the place in the pager and so on.

Comment: @MarkT: I forget to mention that one can use `pagerpos` and `recordpos` options to change the position of information in the pager. For example one can use `pagerpos: "left", recordpos: "left"` to place all 3 information parts in the left part of the pager. One can use other CSS properties (like `display:inline-block;` and other) or/and move the  to reorder the `span.ui-paging-info` and `table.ui-pg-table` after `div.navtable` inside of `jqGrid_toppager_left`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does what I need.